# Horizontal little box before section's heading?

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I cannot find properly what I need about my topic.
I would like to set customized section's heading like in the example, but I am not so good with latex.

Can someone maybe implement my code or suggest me a simple way to do it alone?

Here what I would have:
[image: An example of what I would have]

Here what I have now:
[image]

Here my code:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb} %package for math's formulas
    \usepackage{footnote} %package to set footnotes
    \usepackage{fix-cm} %package to fix size of fonts
    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{titlesec} 
    \usepackage{xhfill}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
    \usepackage{float}


    \titleformat{\section}
    {\raggedright\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{RoyalBlue}{\thesection}{1em}{}

    \begin{document}
    \section*{25$^{th}$ April, 2016}
    \lipsum[1]
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Well, if you want to have `11th April 2016`, type `11`, not `25`… ;o)

Comment: Spätzle? ;-) Ha jo, paßt schu ;-)

Comment: Try something like `\titleformat{\section}[hang]
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{blue}}
  {\rule[0.5ex]{1.5cm}{2pt}\quad}
  {0pt}{}` and then `\section{25\textsuperscript{th} April, 2016}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb} %package for math's formulas
    \usepackage{footnote} %package to set footnotes
    \usepackage{fix-cm} %package to fix size of fonts
    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage{xhfill}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
    \usepackage{float}

\titleformat{\section}
{\raggedright\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{RoyalBlue}}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{name=\section, numberless}
{\raggedright\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{RoyalBlue}}{}{0em}{\rule[\dimexpr0.5\fontdimen 5\font-1.5pt]{2cm}{3pt}\enspace}

\begin{document}

\section*{25$\textup{th}$ April, 2016}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Super!Thanks! It is perfecly what I was looking for! =)